# How can I use ' this symbol in SQL

Tags: sql

I have some names in my language that contains "'", how can I insert this name in SQL?

For example Vyaches'lav, Name'yana

INSERT INTO allnames (nameUa, nameRu, nameRu2, surname) VALUES('{0}','{1}', '{2}', '{3}')".format(Vyaches'lav, Vyaches'lav, Vyaches'lav, Surnamed);

Comment: Don't inject values into the sql command, use parameters to supply these values. Details depend on your programming environment

Comment: yes, thank you so much!